# How to solve Duplicate class java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client

Tags: android, gradle, zxing

I am currently facing a Duplicate class `RuntimeException`. In our current use case we are producing an artifact which is using `com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded`. Our client wants to include our artifact but they are getting a `RuntimeException` during the compilation.
The Exception occurs because they are using `com.google.zxing` which is currently clashing with the journeyapps port of zxing which we are using. Journeyapps did a port of the ZXing Android application as an Android library project, for embedding in an Android application.

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraConfigurationUtils found in modules android-core-3.3.0.jar (com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0) and classes.jar (com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
        at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraConfigurationUtils found in modules android-core-3.3.0.jar (com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0) and classes.jar (com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:132)
        at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:40)
        ... 72 more
```

I have tried to exclude the duplicate classes inside the gradle build file. Using the following code and vise versa.

```
implementation("com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0")
implementation("module which includes com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.6") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing', module: 'android-core'
    }
```

Without a solution.
I even tried to exclude the module inside the configuration. If I do so it is missing during the insertion of the dependencies.

You can reproduce the error using the following code

```
implementation("com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0")
implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0")
```

As I tried to solve the problem for a lot of hours without a solution, I am very thankful for every advise.

Answer (score 11):

this solve for me

add below code in `Android/app/build.gradle` file

```
configurations {
compile.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using this transitive flag maybe this can help you out

```
implementation("module which includes com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.6") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing', module: 'android-core'
        transitive = false
    }
```

Comment: Hi PJain thank you for your reply. I tried to follow your advise to disabling resolution of transitive dependencies in a new sample project with the following code as well as in the real project.
`implementation("com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0")
    implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing', module: 'android-core'
        transitive = false
    }`
Maybe I am missing something out or am I trying to exclude the wrong package?

Comment: Sry, unfortunately it is not working I am receiving the same error. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraConfigurationUtils found in modules android-core-3.3.0.jar (com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0) and classes.jar (com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0)`.

Comment: Is the error solved, if not then can you please upload full Gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to your comments I solved the issue like below image

[image]

```
dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
    }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    generatedDensities = []
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We came to the conclusion that we can not exclude the dependencies because their is a naming issue in case of some classes with com.journeyapps:zxing and com.google.zxing.

We ended up migrating our libary from com.journeyapps:zxing to com.google.zxing.

Thanks to PJain for the advise.